# cPanel error - Failed building wheel for pyodbc

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, cpanel

I am trying to import pyodbc in my main.py file so that I can query a SQL Server database table. In my requirements.txt file I have just 2 lines:

```
Flask==2.0.0 
pyodbc==4.0.30
```

I get the error message "Failed building wheel for pyodbc...failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-45x_gp0m/pyodbc/"
How can I fix this error? I am on a shared hosting plan so I am hoping to address the issue in cPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing dependencies for pyodbc on your server. If your hosting provider is missing at least one, it will show you that error.

You would need root access to install those dependencies. If your server doesn't have installed it, pyodbc not will work.

Read the following documentations:

- https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Install
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15